# Retrieving data from local storage not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms, jquery-mobile

I can save to local storage, but when I add code to retrieve the data it does not work. I can see the code has been saved as I have checked using F12 in chrome. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-
 1.4.5.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form>
 <input type="text" id="task" placeholder="name">
 <input type="text" id="date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
 <input type="button" class="add-row" value="Add Row">

 </form>
 <table id="task_table">
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
 </thead> 
 <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>steve</td>
        <td>13/12/1956</td>
    </tr>

 </tbody>

 </table>
 <button id="saveAll">Save List</button>


 <script>$("#saveAll").click(function(e) {


 var listBirthdays = [];
 $("table td").each(function(){
   listBirthdays.push(this.innerHTML);
 })
 localStorage.setItem('birthdayList', JSON.stringify(listBirthdays));
 });

 </script>


 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $(".add-row").on('click',function(){
    var task = $("#task").val();
    var date = $("#date").val();
    var markup = "<tr><td>" + task + "</td><td>" + date + "</td></tr>";
    $('table tbody').append(markup);

 });


            }
     );

;


</script>
```

Below is shown the code that I tried to use to reload the data from storage.

```
loadList();

function loadList() {
if (localStorage.getItem('birthdayList')){ 
    var listBirthdays = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('birthdayList'));
    $("table td").each(function(i){
      this.innerHTML = listBirthdays [i];
    })
}
```

}
   });

When i add code that should retrieve the data it does not add it back to the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the `.each` loop in your `loadList` function.

Let's assume the stored value looks like this:

```
'["steve", "13/12/1956", "jane", "04/04/1987", "peter", "01/03/1999"]'
```

It gets parsed and loaded into the `listBirthdays` array:

```
console.log(listBirthdays[0]) // -> "steve"
console.log(listBirthdays[1]) // -> "13/12/1956"
console.log(listBirthdays[2]) // -> "jane"
                              //     …etc.
```

Then, the `.each` loop runs on your table cells:

```
$("table td").each(function(i){ … });
```

…but the table body is still just one row with two cells:

```
<td>steve</td>
<td>13/12/1956</td>
```

So, the loop index (`i`) never gets past 1  – 0 for the cell with "steve", 1 for the cell with Steve's birth date. Then the loop ends, because there are no more cells:

```
// i = 0
this.innerHTML = listBirthdays[0]; // listBirthdays[0] = "steve"

// i = 1
this.innerHTML = listBirthdays[1]; // listBirthdays[1] = "13/12/1956"

// 'i' will never get to 2 as there are no more cells, listBirthdays[2] (and further) will never be used
```

The cell content is replaced with the first two values from the `listBirthdays` array – `steve` is replaced with `steve` and `13/12/1956` is replaced with `13/12/1956`. So it looks like nothing happened at all.

The simple solution is to just add the needed empty rows/cells before loading the data into table:

```
function loadList() {
  if (localStorage.getItem("birthdayList")) {
    var listBirthdays = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("birthdayList"));
    // calculate how many rows we need:
    var newRows = listBirthdays.length / 2; // for 2 columns
    // replace tbody content with the new rows:
    $("tbody").html("<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>".repeat(newRows));
    // table now has two cells for each name–date pair
    $("tbody td").each(function(i, cell) {
      cell.innerHTML = listBirthdays[i];
    });
  }
}
```

[Working example on Codepen](https://codepen.io/helb/pen/vWJVgM) (tried to post it here, but `localStorage` does not work in SO snippets)

However, a more logical approach would be to render the cells based on the data, not the other way around.

Comment: Thank you for explaining in detail what was wrong and supplying a solution. The Codepen example is very helpful as well. Once again many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As @helb already explained the problem with your code. There is an alternate solution to the problem, just change your loadList function to this:-

```
 function loadList() {


    if (localStorage.getItem('birthdayList')) {

        var listBirthdays = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('birthdayList'));

        $("#task_table").find("tr").remove();

        for (i = 0; i < listBirthdays.length - 1; i = i + 2) {
            $('#task_table tbody').append('<tr>' + '<td>' + listBirthdays[i] + '</td>' + '<td>' + listBirthdays[i + 1] + '</td>' + '</tr>');
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me an alternate way of solving this problem, it is really appreciated. Thanks again.